# Backup List in Sharepoint 2010 in Shell

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, backup, export

I want to backup a List of Sharepoint 2010 using the powershell.

I can backup the list using the central Administration and can also backup the whole Site using

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us -Path \\public\backup.cmp
```

But when I try to export a specific List (with the path that is also shown using the Central Administration):

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us/Lists/MyList -Path \\public\backup.cmp
```

I receive the error:

> "The URL provided is invalid. Only valid URLs
>   that are site collections or sites are allowed to be exported using
>   stsadm.exe"

I also tried

`Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us -Path \\public\backup.cmp -ItemURL` http://siteurl:22222/en-us/Lists/MyList 
getting the same error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to fiddle with the `ItemUrl` parameter value:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us -Path \\public\backup.cmp
  -ItemUrl /Lists/MyList
```

or

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us -Path \\public\backup.cmp
  -ItemUrl /en-us/Lists/MyList
```

or

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://siteurl:22222/en-us -Path \\public\backup.cmp
  -ItemUrl "/Lists/MyList"
```

Different sources show different syntax:

- [SharePoint 2010 Granular Backup-Restore Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1.aspx)
- [Failing to export with Export-SPWeb](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/a416941c-34c5-4ef7-af0d-b45ad7fa6a5f/)

Comment: I had to get rid of the slash in the ItemUrl parameter value, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the following kind of setup:

```
Site Collection e.g.  http://localhost:81
|
|-> Subsite 1 e.g. tools (http://localhost:81/tools)
    |
    |-> Subsite 2 e.g. admin (http://localhost:81/tools/admin)
```

I found the following worked for lists on the subsite:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://<site>:<port>/<subsite1>/<subsite2> -ItemUrl /<subsite1>/<subsite2>/<listName> -Path <localpath>/<filename>.cmp -IncludeVersions All
```

e.g.

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://localhost:81/tools/admin/ -ItemUrl /tools/admin/RequestList -Path C:/Temp/Backup.cmp -IncludeVersions All
```

To ensure you've got the right url for your list, use the following command (thanks to HAZET here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/a1f48e70-9360-440f-b160-525fbf2b8412/):

```
$(Get-SPWeb -identity  http://<site>:<port>/<subsite1>/<subsite2>).lists | ft title,  @{Name="itemURL"; Expression = { $_.parentWebURL + "/" + $_.RootFolder}}
```

e.g.

```
$(Get-SPWeb -identity http://localhost:81/tools/admin/).lists | ft title, @{Name="itemURL"; Expression = { $_.parentWebURL + "/" + $_.RootFolder}}
```

Some examples of various errors I encountered whilst trying to get this to work:

1. `The URL provided is invalid`
2. `Export-SPWeb : <nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack> At line:1 char:13`
3. `CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb: SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], SPException FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWeb`

Some things to check:

- Check that -Identity has the trailing slash i.e. `http://localhost:81/`
- Check that you have the complete URL in Identity (if using subsites, include subsites)
- Check that the path where you're trying to store your export file exists
- Check that your ItemUrl is correct (i.e. starts with / and is a directory, not a specific file e.g. is `/tools/admin/RequestsList`, not `/tools/admin/RequestsList/AllItems.aspx`
- Check that you have permissions to perform the export

Further info that might be helpful:

- Identity: The URL of your SharePoint site
- ItemUrl: The relative URL of your list/document library
- Path:     The target filename and location for the exported list e.g. C:/Temp/backup.cmp
- IncludeVersion: What versions of the document you wish to export.

Export-SPWeb
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Export a site, list or document library in SharePoint 2010
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Import a list or document library in SharePoint 2010
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx